# jQuery selector for number input

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors

I have this drop down code:

```
$('#addDropdown').click(function() {
   var $d = $('<select class="dropdown"><option selected="selected" value="null" rel="null">Choose your data!</option><option value="1" rel="2">Option 1</option><option value="1" rel="2">Option 2</option><option value="14" rel="15">Option 3</option></select><input type="number" min="1" max="99" class="multiplier" name="multiplier" value="1" size="3"/><br/>').fadeIn().delay(1000);

   $('#dropdownContainer').append($d);
});
```

and I'm passing the values to an ajax function with this code, i use a button to append more drop downs with the same values:

```
    var dropdowns = $(".dropdown"),
        one = [],
        two = [],
        mult = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
   one.push(dropdowns.eq(i).find('option:selected').attr('rel'));
   two.push(dropdowns.eq(i).val());
   mult.push(dropdowns.eq(i).val() * dropdowns.eq(i).find('input[name=multiplier]').val())
 }
```

for the multi option I want to take the value attribute that is selected and multiply it with the value from the number input... my selector isn't working for the input, how can I select that multiplier input??

Comment: You have written `[name=multiplier]` ?? I don't understand why people don't read jQuery docs at all. read about jQuery selectors. They are very important

Comment: @Imdad what is the problem of `[name=multiplier]`?? It sounds that you should read the docs.

Comment: @lmdad That's the correct attribute equals selector, OP just got dom hierarchy wrong since that's not a descendant

Comment: what's wrong with it? I don't understand why people wouldn't just post a correction, rather than try to criticize someone...

Comment: There is no input field with name `multiplier` in the code you posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only finds elements which are descendants of the currently matched set; since you want adjacent elements (siblings), use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) (probably best in this case) or [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
for(var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
   one.push(dropdowns.eq(i).find('option:selected').attr('rel'));
   two.push(dropdowns.eq(i).val());
   mult.push(dropdowns.eq(i).val() * dropdowns.eq(i).next('input[name=multiplier]').val())
}
```

Comment: @tdun No problem! Also, the class selector may perform better than the attribute selector, so if your `<input>` elements have class `multiplier`, it may be better to use `input.multiplier` rather than `input[name=multiplier]`. Not a huge difference though (they both appear to be css based)

Comment: how would I pass these arrays to the .ajax() "data" section? it's only retrieving the last value from the array

Answer (score 0):

```
mult.push(dropdowns.eq(i).val() * $('.multiplier').val())
```

Comment: I used .next() because I have multiple drop downs and each has their own number input, thank you though!